# How do I prevent that a variable gets added twice into my json file?

Tags: python, json

I am trying to get some IDs into an json file but I don't want it to add IDs that's already in the file.

The IDs do get added twice if I run the code twice, but if I run it a third time it stays with all IDs duplicate.

```
import json

with open('match_id.json') as f:
    match_id_dict = json.load(f)

match = list(match_id_dict.keys())

with open('erediviseomg1.json') as f:
    jsondata = json.load(f)
    for event in jsondata['events']:
        match_id = event['id']
        if match_id not in match:
            match_id_dict[match_id] = None

with open ('match_id.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(match_id_dict, f)
```

When I run this code once, I get this output in my json file:

```
{"11399372": null, "11399373": null, "11399375": null, "11399376": null, "11399381": null, "11399382": null, "11399388": null, "11399387": null, "11399393": null}
```

But when I run the same code again, this is what the json file looks like:

```
{"11399372": null, "11399373": null, "11399375": null, "11399376": null, "11399381": null, "11399382": null, "11399388": null, "11399387": null, "11399393": null, "11399372": null, "11399373": null, "11399375": null, "11399376": null, "11399381": null, "11399382": null, "11399388": null, "11399387": null, "11399393": null}
```

And if I run the code again, nothing happens, it stays like this. How do I prevent it from adding already existing IDs?

Comment: I'm guessing this is due to mismatching types. Either `match_id_dict`'s keys are integers (I seem to recall that `json.load` does automatically convert strings to integers when it is able to), or `match_id` is an integer. If `match_id` is an integer, and `match` is a list of strings, you'll enter the body of the if-statement. Or, if `match_id` is a string, and `match` is a list of integers, same thing.